# Should "website-analytics-tools" and "analytics" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

- [analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics) - 260
- [website-analytics-tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-analytics-tools) - 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these two tags should be merged.  They are both about analytics tools.  It seems to me that "analytics" should be sufficient for this tag since the entire site is about websites.

Comment: Yep merging them would be much more ideal.